# Reverse for 'success' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

Tags: django, reverse

I'm starting my Django (1.5) project and When I register the url of a view I get this error!

#### The Html

```
<form action="{% url 'MainApp:success' %}" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputText">Nombres</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" id="inputText" placeholder="Nombres" name="nombre" required>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

#### App.view

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def index(request):
     return render_to_response('TeamCheetah/index.html')

def auth(request):
     if request.POST['registra'] is 'registra':
         user = User.objects.create_user(request.POST['nombre'], request.POST['email'], request.POST['pass'])
         user.last_name = request.POST['apellido']
         user.save()
     return render_to_response('TeamCheetah/Actions.html')
```

#### App.urls

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from MainApp_TeamCheetah import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^success/$', views.auth, name='success'),
)
```

#### Mysite.urls

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    url(r'^$', include('MainApp_TeamCheetah.urls', namespace="MainApp")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

It marks the error in the form. I believe it's related with the view auth i created because when I use the action: index in the form, it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

- `url` tags are written without `'`, so `{% url MainApp:success %}` when you're linking to a URL by name and not by view path. This shouldn't affect things but that's how they're canonically written.
- More importantly, the following line has a regex that ends with a `$` which means it won't match to any URLs that have something after that:

  `url(r'^$', include('MainApp_TeamCheetah.urls', namespace="MainApp")),`

  That would explain why it does match `index` but not `success`.